# Extract tar file using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, tar

Hi I am working with Bash Script and i have difficulty on extracting a tar file and inside of the tar file is another tar file . Please see below code and please provide me with feedback because the only thing that the code do will just extract the the first tar file and remove it.

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(df -h)
bundle=$(awk -F = '{print $2}' config.txt)
bundlename=$(echo $bundle | awk -F / '{print $11}')  
echo "$output"

wget $bundle
echo "$bundlename"
tar -xzvf "$bundlename"
rm -vf "$bundlename"
```

My question is what is the right way/code to extract all the tar file inside the tar file ?.

Comment: you should extract the content again from the extracted tar file.

Comment: how should I do that ? can you give me sample code that will extract tar file inside the tar file with different tar name ?

Comment: added an answer to this.

Comment: does it answer the question? if yes, please mark it as answered.

Comment: I've tried it yes it can only extract . But is there any easiest way to extract all the tar files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pipe the output of the tar extract to the `tar command` again to run it. for example:

```
tar -xvf xyz.tar |grep '\.tar$' | xargs -n 1 | tar -xvf
```

but this will only extract one level tar files, if the extracted tar contains another tar, then again you will have to pipe it. I hope you get the point.